# Do special Emoji collected during Challenge mode count toward my collection?

Tags: disney-emoji-blitz

In regular mode, if I drop a special Emoji to the bottom of the playing field, it counts towards my collection that I am currently unlocking. Is the same true of ones that get dropped to the bottom in challenge mode? I don't get the same screen after where it shows me I unlocked collection Emoji, so I am not sure.